# How to remove background from the image to efficently apply k-means clustering

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am working on a project to classify disease in a leaf. I am trying to apply k means clustering so that the diseased area can be clustered together and then I can extract the features from that clustered area. However, due to the background, I am not able to cluster then correctly as the diseased area is clustered with the background.

My goal is to cluster the diseased area and then extract the features from the diseased area to train the classifier.

**Approach 1 -**
I tried to draw a contour around the leaf and then use the min area rect function from OpenCV to draw a rectangle and subsequently, I can crop but the contour is not fine enough to remove the background.

Below is the code:

```
lower_green = np.array((60-s,100,50))
upper_green = np.array((60+s,255,255))
name = "Apple_healthy/image_85.jpg"
bgr = cv2.imread(name)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=50)
_, contours, hier =   cv2.findContours(mask.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
cnt = contours[-1]
cv2.drawContours(bgr,[cnt],0,(0,0,255), 2)
cv2.imshow('image', bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(bgr,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
cv2.imshow('sad',bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Output of approach-1]

**Approach 2 -**
Directly apply k means clustering to the image. But in this approach, I'm not able to cluster the diseased area together as the diseased area is clustered with the background. Below is the code:

```
img = cv2.imread('Apple_black_rot/image_85.jpg')

Z = img.reshape((-1,3))

# convert to np.float32
Z = np.float32(Z)

# define criteria, number of clusters(K) and apply kmeans()
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
K = 16
ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,K,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

# Now convert back into uint8, and make original image
center = np.uint8(center)
res = center[label.flatten()]
res2 = res.reshape((img.shape))

cv2.imshow('res2',res2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Output of approach-2]

Original Image

[image: Original Image]

Comment: Though it may seem obvious to you, I don't know what you call the diseased area and the background. I see a violet substrate, a black shadow, a green leaf and stains in various shades of brown. What is what ? Please be explicit.

Comment: The background includes violet substrate and black shadow. The diseased area includes various stains of brown color on the leaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diseased areas have a distinct hue. You can extract the hue component (from the HSV system) and get a grayscale image, from which segmentation shouldn't be a problem, except maybe along the shadow edges (see pictures). But the shadow can also be easily detected and you can neutralize this area.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your ans. I've extracted the hue component and got the first image but I couldn't follow after that.

Comment: @rishi: this is an easy case of binarization.

Comment: for the same image I extracted the hue from the image and applied Otsu’s Binarization on hue using opencv but I was not able to get the desired result i.e similar to your second image.

Comment: @rishi: Otsu can't work here because there are essentially three shades of gray (background, leaf, stains) and two possibilities to select a threshold in between. You can set the threshold by hand.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. Since I've the locations of the required area from the binary image, is it possible that I can view only these locations of the binary image in the orignal rgb image.

Comment: thanks for correcting me, I was of the view that in the rgb image only the diseased area will be visible. How should I approach image segmentation using k means after this step.

Comment: @rishi: your image is already segmented. What more do you hope to get with k-means ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143439/discussion-between-rishi-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: I guess there wont be a difference after applying k-means. Thanks alot. I want to extract feature using the glcm matrix by passing the segmented image. For each channel i.e H,S and V i want to extract features. How should I extract features from the S and V channel.

Comment: @rishi: sorry, I am not solving your whole application. Post another question, with details.

Comment: sorry I didn't realize that will do it. Thanks a lot for your help.